# Authenticate a Django/Appengine project using Firebase

Tags: python, django, firebase, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I currently have google and facebook authentication for my application. I would like to add firebase-auth as the backend for my Django/appengine backend. The tutorial i followed (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine) only show how to use it for a python  Flask backend.

Does anyone know how to set up firebase in a Django backend that uses appengine?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the same logic mentioned in the tutorial that you indicated here. As per the documentation informs:

> The sample app uses Flask because of its simplicity and ease of use, but the concepts and technologies explored are applicable regardless of which framework you use.

So, the concepts are the same for any framework, which should work for you using Django. Since there isn't a specific tutorial for the use of Django, I recommend you take a look at the below article, to better understand the integration of Firebase and Django, so you can implement it on your

- [Python Django with Google Firebase : Getting Started, Intro, Basic Configuration & Firebase Authentication #Part1](https://www.hackanons.com/2018/03/python-django-with-google-firebase.html)

Let me know if the information helped you!